# RF ground plane and pour question

Tags: rf

Is it a good practice to make a separate RF ground for a part of the board consisting of the RF module and antenna connector?

The PCB is 4 layer board, with 2 internal planes. The top and bottom layer ground pours around the RF parts are completely separated from the digital ground pour (rest of the board). The GND internal plane is connected to the rest of the plane in a single slot, and that is the only connection between RF ground and digital ground.

Comment: What do  the various data sheets for the RF components tell you?

Comment: Its hard to tell specifically, each one has something different. Would this approach be okay?

Comment: @ningbo, all we know about your design is that it includes an RF module of some kind and an antenna. Do you think that's enough for us to be able to answer your question?